# Secure communication between two instances of same Android app

Tags: android, ssl, ipsec

I'm currently designing a system that should allow two instances of the same Android app to communicate securely.

1) Is the SSL protocol the best choice? Or I should move to IPsec!?
  (I am thinking of exploiting a client-server model with the server creating a SSLserversocket and waiting for client, a P2P model would by better actually, but I have no idea how to do it right now)
2) Is there a way to make a 2-way authentication by using the SSL protocol?
3) Is there any tutorial that can help me to understand how to create SSL sockets in Android?

Thank u very much!

Comment: two instance means?? running same apps in two device? or same app with different package name in same device?

Comment: Hey StinePike, yes two instances running in two different devices :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use message queue's with ssl support, but also can start with :

developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

for messaging and something or similar to

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-des.html

if you can have pre-shared keys distributed with applications separately. otherwise asymmetric encryption (ssl) should be considered.